# Chrome input history dropdown has the same thing in multiple fonts

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, fonts

Stumbled across this weird behaviour when I was working on the search for our site.

When I was using the search on our site, i would get no matches for results that I knew definitely existed.  When I retyped it, the input field history showed my search in a different font.

Typing the search from scratch would return the correct results.  But when I clicked the history item with the weird font, it would still show no results.

What caused this to happen?  I don't have any other language enabled on my pc...

[image: Weird font behaviour]

Comment: if you want an answer to a question, please remember to be specific: what cms is the site using, what produces the search box, did you write it? then show or link to the relevant code. Do you not know? Then instead of stackoverflow you should be asking the person that did write it, first. The [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help article explains how to improve this post so that it can actually be answered.

Comment: I would be more specific if I could, but this appears to be a general issue with Chrome input fields.  It is not limited to a piece of code or this particular text field, or even this site.  In fact these bizarre values are in my input field history and come up on any site I go to.

Comment: in that case you want to include a jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com, or thimble.mozilla.org example that replicates this behaviour for you, and then hope someone else has the same problem when they load that up?